# Referenced CTE in CASE expression is returning null values. My CTE works correctly as standalone query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case, common-table-expression, sql-null

I have a query that works as intended, and I need to build upon it to include a new column that has conditional values. The new column will result with either a date or a string 'na'. To accomplish this, I wrote a CASE statement, and then referenced the CTE within the statement to provide the conditional logic.

The main query (without the CASE statement addition) works as a standalone query, and the CTE works correctly and provides the correct date when it is ran as an independent query.

This is my first time including an INSERT statement. Please let me know if I messed this up.

Main query table:

```
CREATE TABLE mainquery(
   Region_ID       INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,messageid       INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,name            VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  ,DateReceived    DATETIME  NOT NULL
  ,Datemodified    DATETIME  NOT NULL
  ,Messagestatus   INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,clientid        VARCHAR(255)
  ,ClientFirstName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  ,ClientLastName  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  ,clientdob       DATETIME  NOT NULL
  ,Supervisorid    INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,visitid         VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  ,SuperName       VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  ,SuperID         VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  ,colldate        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  ,colltime        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  ,Ordername       VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  ,errorlogs       VARCHAR(8000) NOT NULL
  ,comments        VARCHAR(255)
  ,last_visit_date DATETIME
);
INSERT INTO mainquery(Region_ID,messageid,name,DateReceived,Datemodified,Messagestatus,clientid,ClientFirstName,ClientLastName,clientdob,Supervisorid,visitid,SuperName,SuperID,colldate,colltime,Ordername,errorlogs,comments,last_visit_date) VALUES (1,116113842,'R1_OG','2022-06-09 13:07:52.000','2022-06-09 13:07:52.000',4,'123456789','Fake','Name','1980-01-01  00:00:00.000',123,'741852963','Joe','J1234','2022-05-06','16:27:00','fake_order','Supervisor Match not found',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO mainquery(Region_ID,messageid,name,DateReceived,Datemodified,Messagestatus,clientid,ClientFirstName,ClientLastName,clientdob,Supervisorid,visitid,SuperName,SuperID,colldate,colltime,Ordername,errorlogs,comments,last_visit_date) VALUES (2,159753205,'SEL North','2022-03-12 04:07:85.000','2018-06-25 12:07:00.000',2,'963741258','Funny','Namely','1999-02-03 00:00:00.000',98524,'159654','David','DL652','2018-01-24','09:03:00','real_fake','Supervisor Match not found',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO mainquery(Region_ID,messageid,name,DateReceived,Datemodified,Messagestatus,clientid,ClientFirstName,ClientLastName,clientdob,Supervisorid,visitid,SuperName,SuperID,colldate,colltime,Ordername,errorlogs,comments,last_visit_date) VALUES (3,951789369,'Blue_South','2022-03-11 12:08:33.000','2022-03-11 12:08:33.001',2,NULL,'Who','Ami','2000-08-11 00:00:00.000',789456,'963123','Shirley','S852','2017-05-14','09:30:00','example_order','Client Match not found','here is a comment','na');
INSERT INTO mainquery(Region_ID,messageid,name,DateReceived,Datemodified,Messagestatus,clientid,ClientFirstName,ClientLastName,clientdob,Supervisorid,visitid,SuperName,SuperID,colldate,colltime,Ordername,errorlogs,comments,last_visit_date) VALUES (4,294615883,'Mtn-Dew','2017-09-06 16:20:00.000','2017-09-06 16:20:00.001',2,NULL,'Why','Tho','1970-11-20 00:00:00.000',9631475,'159654852','Bob','B420','2022-09-22','10:25:31','example_example','Client Match not found',NULL,'na');
INSERT INTO mainquery(Region_ID,messageid,name,DateReceived,Datemodified,Messagestatus,clientid,ClientFirstName,ClientLastName,clientdob,Supervisorid,visitid,SuperName,SuperID,colldate,colltime,Ordername,errorlogs,comments,last_visit_date) VALUES (5,789963258,'Home-Base','2022-07-11 15:22:40.000','2022-07-11 15:22:40.001',2,NULL,'Where','Aru','1987-01-06 00:00:00.000',805690123,'805460378','Carlos','C999','2022-07-11','07:30:45','order_order','Client Match not found',NULL,'na');
```

CTE temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE CTE(
   uid        INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,clientdob  DATETIME  NOT NULL
  ,clienttype INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,date       DATETIME  NOT NULL
  ,visitid    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  ,Region_ID  INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,facilityid INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,locationid INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO CTE(uid,clientdob,clienttype,date,visitid,Region_ID,facilityid,locationid) VALUES (123456789,'1980-01-01  00:00:00.000',3,'2022-09-18 00:00:00.000','741852963',1,240,32);
INSERT INTO CTE(uid,clientdob,clienttype,date,visitid,Region_ID,facilityid,locationid) VALUES (963741258,'1999-02-03 00:00:00.000',3,'2022-05-11 00:00:00.000','159654',2,606,123);
INSERT INTO CTE(uid,clientdob,clienttype,date,visitid,Region_ID,facilityid,locationid) VALUES (852654320,'1994-05-11 00:00:00.000',3,'2019-03-18 00:00:00.000','123456',3,632,12);
INSERT INTO CTE(uid,clientdob,clienttype,date,visitid,Region_ID,facilityid,locationid) VALUES (85360123,'1997-08-16 00:00:00.000',3,'2021-02-19 00:00:00.000','7896451',4,856,147);
INSERT INTO CTE(uid,clientdob,clienttype,date,visitid,Region_ID,facilityid,locationid) VALUES (85311456,'1964-10-31 00:00:00.000',3,'2016-02-14 00:00:00.000','85263',5,852,15);
```

Expected view:

[screenshot of wide table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wdk73.png)
Edited to add: I goofed with the 'expected view' screenshot. The screenshot shows an example of what the table looks like right now. The desired view is for there to be dates in `last_visit_date` (in the appropriate rows), instead of Null.

My issue is the following: the query still works with the new CASE statement and the CTE, except that instead of providing the proper date in the new column, it returns a Null value.

Am I approaching this query with the wrong idea? I thought I was on the right path but now I am doubting myself. I tried utilizing a subquery instead of a CTE, but I received an error message stating that the query could not be completed due to there being more than one result per row.

Here is my main query and associated CTE:

```
WITH last_visit (uid, clientdob, clienttype, date, visitid, Region_ID, facilityid, locationid) AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        u.uid, u.clientdob, u.clienttype, 
        CONVERT(varchar, v.date) AS last_visit, 
        v.visitid, u.Region_ID, v.facilityid, v.locationid
    FROM 
        users u
    LEFT JOIN 
        visit v ON u.uid = v.clientid
                AND u.Region_ID = v.Region_ID
    WHERE 
        v.date = (SELECT MAX(v.date) FROM visit v WHERE v.clientid = u.uid)
        AND u.clienttype = 3
        AND u.uid <> 8663
        AND u.ulname NOT LIKE '%test%'
        AND u.ulname NOT LIKE '%unidentified%'
        AND u.delflvg = 0
        AND v.visittype = 1
        AND v.facilityid <> 0
        AND v.deleteflag = 0
)
SELECT 
    r.Region_ID, r.messageid, l.name, r.DateReceived, r.DateModified, 
    r.MessageStatus, r.clientid, r.ClientFirstName, r.ClientLastName, r.clientdob, 
    r.Supervisorid, r.visitid, r.SuperName, r.SuperID, r.colldate, r.colltime, 
    r.OrderName, r.errorlogs, a.comments,
    CASE 
        WHEN r.errorlogs LIKE 'Supervisor Match not found' 
            THEN lv.date 
            ELSE 'na' 
    END AS last_visit_date
FROM
    electronicresults r
JOIN 
    recelectronicresults a ON r.messageid = a.messageid 
                           AND r.Region_ID = a.Region_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    users u ON r.clientid = u.uid
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    visit v ON r.clientid = v.clientid AND r.visitid = v.visitid
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    last_visit lv ON r.visitid = lv.visitid 
                  AND r.clientid = lv.uid
JOIN 
    lblist l ON r.lbid = l.id 
             AND r.Region_ID = l.Region_ID
WHERE 
    r.MessageStatus IN (0, 2, 4)
    AND a.actiontaken = 0
    AND l.deleteflag = 0
GROUP BY 
    r.Region_ID, r.messageid, l.name, r.DateReceived, r.DateModified, 
    r.MessageStatus, r.clientid, r.ClientFirstName, r.ClientLastName, 
    r.clientdob, r.Supervisorid, r.visitid, r.SuperName, r.SuperID, 
    r.colldate, r.colltime, r.OrderName, r.errorlogs, a.comments, lv.date
```

I thank you for taking the time to read this, and any support, hints, tips are greatly appreciated

Comment: [`Case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is an _expression_, not a _statement_, and any given `case` can only return a single data type according to the rules for [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question, e.g. fewer joins and more sample data would help us help you.

Comment: To be clear, are you saying that the case expression above returns the literal string 'null' for `last_visit_date`, or the null value? Either one seems impossible, unless the date coming from the subquery were already that value.

Comment: HABO - I am currently in the process of making some sample data that you and others can look at. Thank you for the post suggestions.

Comment: Xedni - It returns the null value, not the string literal 'Null'. Sorry for the confusion. Original post edited to reflect this clarification.

Comment: Aside: Bad habits to kick include using string data types without a length, e.g. `CONVERT(varchar, v.date)`. The [default length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) is `30` in a `cast` or `convert`, otherwise `1`. It's not worth saving a few keystrokes for something that will, sooner or later, get cut'n'pasted inappropriately and nibble thee.

Comment: `Last_visit_date` is of datatype `DateTime` so how can you insert `'na'` into it?

Comment: @Soerman I thought that `Last_Visit_Date` was calculated in the `select` using `lv.Date` which is the result of `CONVERT(varchar, v.date)` in the CTE. Did I follow the curious chain of name changes incorrectly? Or did you just look at the DDL for `mainquery` and assume that there wasn't a shell game of names going on?

Comment: @HABO haha yeah, you're right. I looked at the DDL.. I copied the `mainquery` and `CTE` to try to see if there's something wrong with the joins and got errors for the insert. Because since both queries work standalone my first guess would be the join.

Comment: @Soerman - thank you for taking the time to look at my post. Yes - I used `CONVERT()` to allow the entry of `varchar` strings into `last_visit_date`. You are thinking that [clearly] there must be something wrong with the join, considering both queries work independently?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's affecting your results, but when you do a `LEFT OUTER JOIN <table>` and then in the WHERE clause `<table>.<column> = <value>` you effectively turn that `LEFT OUTER JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`. If you are truly needing a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` then the conditions in your `WHERE` clause should be moved up into their relative `ON` clause.

Comment: @JNevill - I experimented with your suggestion and unfortunately it didn't yield any improvements with the relevant query. It DID however help me with another query that was taking a very long time to result, and optimized it to the point where it resulted in less than 60 seconds. So thank you for teaching me something new!

Answer (score 0):

I was hopeful when you provided a script to create tables and sample data, but unfortunately the script you provided does not work - you cannot `INSERT` the value 'na' in a `DATETIME` column as was pointed out. Also, one of the sample `DATETIME` values is not valid: '2022-03-12 04:07:85.000' (there is no time with 85 seconds). Anyway, I corrected the issues and pressed forward.

There is one issue in your sample query - the `CASE` statement returns a `DATETIME` in one case and a `VARCHAR` in the other case. This is not legal - all cases must return the same data type. Instead of returning 'na' I opted for `NULL`.

Once I commented out all the tables you did not include, I was able to get a running query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mainquery(
   Region_ID       INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,messageid       INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,name            VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  ,DateReceived    DATETIME  NOT NULL
  ,Datemodified    DATETIME  NOT NULL
  ,Messagestatus   INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,clientid        VARCHAR(255)
  ,ClientFirstName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  ,ClientLastName  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  ,clientdob       DATETIME  NOT NULL
  ,Supervisorid    INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,visitid         VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  ,SuperName       VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  ,SuperID         VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  ,colldate        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  ,colltime        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  ,Ordername       VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  ,errorlogs       VARCHAR(8000) NOT NULL
  ,comments        VARCHAR(255)
  ,last_visit_date DATETIME
);
INSERT INTO mainquery(Region_ID,messageid,name,DateReceived,Datemodified,Messagestatus,clientid,ClientFirstName,ClientLastName,clientdob,Supervisorid,visitid,SuperName,SuperID,colldate,colltime,Ordername,errorlogs,comments,last_visit_date) VALUES (1,116113842,'R1_OG','2022-06-09 13:07:52.000','2022-06-09 13:07:52.000',4,'123456789','Fake','Name','1980-01-01  00:00:00.000',123,'741852963','Joe','J1234','2022-05-06','16:27:00','fake_order','Supervisor Match not found',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO mainquery(Region_ID,messageid,name,DateReceived,Datemodified,Messagestatus,clientid,ClientFirstName,ClientLastName,clientdob,Supervisorid,visitid,SuperName,SuperID,colldate,colltime,Ordername,errorlogs,comments,last_visit_date) VALUES (2,159753205,'SEL North','2022-03-12 04:07:55.000','2018-06-25 12:07:00.000',2,'963741258','Funny','Namely','1999-02-03 00:00:00.000',98524,'159654','David','DL652','2018-01-24','09:03:00','real_fake','Supervisor Match not found',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO mainquery(Region_ID,messageid,name,DateReceived,Datemodified,Messagestatus,clientid,ClientFirstName,ClientLastName,clientdob,Supervisorid,visitid,SuperName,SuperID,colldate,colltime,Ordername,errorlogs,comments,last_visit_date) VALUES (3,951789369,'Blue_South','2022-03-11 12:08:33.000','2022-03-11 12:08:33.001',2,NULL,'Who','Ami','2000-08-11 00:00:00.000',789456,'963123','Shirley','S852','2017-05-14','09:30:00','example_order','Client Match not found','here is a comment',NULL);
INSERT INTO mainquery(Region_ID,messageid,name,DateReceived,Datemodified,Messagestatus,clientid,ClientFirstName,ClientLastName,clientdob,Supervisorid,visitid,SuperName,SuperID,colldate,colltime,Ordername,errorlogs,comments,last_visit_date) VALUES (4,294615883,'Mtn-Dew','2017-09-06 16:20:00.000','2017-09-06 16:20:00.001',2,NULL,'Why','Tho','1970-11-20 00:00:00.000',9631475,'159654852','Bob','B420','2022-09-22','10:25:31','example_example','Client Match not found',NULL,NULL);
INSERT INTO mainquery(Region_ID,messageid,name,DateReceived,Datemodified,Messagestatus,clientid,ClientFirstName,ClientLastName,clientdob,Supervisorid,visitid,SuperName,SuperID,colldate,colltime,Ordername,errorlogs,comments,last_visit_date) VALUES (5,789963258,'Home-Base','2022-07-11 15:22:40.000','2022-07-11 15:22:40.001',2,NULL,'Where','Aru','1987-01-06 00:00:00.000',805690123,'805460378','Carlos','C999','2022-07-11','07:30:45','order_order','Client Match not found',NULL,NULL);


CREATE TABLE CTE(
   uid        INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,clientdob  DATETIME  NOT NULL
  ,clienttype INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,date       DATETIME  NOT NULL
  ,visitid    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  ,Region_ID  INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,facilityid INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,locationid INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO CTE(uid,clientdob,clienttype,date,visitid,Region_ID,facilityid,locationid) VALUES (123456789,'1980-01-01  00:00:00.000',3,'2022-09-18 00:00:00.000','741852963',1,240,32);
INSERT INTO CTE(uid,clientdob,clienttype,date,visitid,Region_ID,facilityid,locationid) VALUES (963741258,'1999-02-03 00:00:00.000',3,'2022-05-11 00:00:00.000','159654',2,606,123);
INSERT INTO CTE(uid,clientdob,clienttype,date,visitid,Region_ID,facilityid,locationid) VALUES (852654320,'1994-05-11 00:00:00.000',3,'2019-03-18 00:00:00.000','123456',3,632,12);
INSERT INTO CTE(uid,clientdob,clienttype,date,visitid,Region_ID,facilityid,locationid) VALUES (85360123,'1997-08-16 00:00:00.000',3,'2021-02-19 00:00:00.000','7896451',4,856,147);
INSERT INTO CTE(uid,clientdob,clienttype,date,visitid,Region_ID,facilityid,locationid) VALUES (85311456,'1964-10-31 00:00:00.000',3,'2016-02-14 00:00:00.000','85263',5,852,15);


SELECT 
    r.Region_ID, r.messageid, r.DateReceived, r.DateModified, 
    r.MessageStatus, r.clientid, r.ClientFirstName, r.ClientLastName, r.clientdob, 
    r.Supervisorid, r.visitid, r.SuperName, r.SuperID, r.colldate, r.colltime, 
    r.OrderName, r.errorlogs, 
    CASE 
        WHEN r.errorlogs LIKE 'Supervisor Match not found' 
            THEN lv.date 
            ELSE NULL 
    END AS last_visit_date
FROM
    mainquery r
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    CTE lv ON r.visitid = lv.visitid 
                  AND r.clientid = lv.uid
WHERE 
    r.MessageStatus IN (0, 2, 4)
GROUP BY 
    r.Region_ID, r.messageid, r.DateReceived, r.DateModified, 
    r.MessageStatus, r.clientid, r.ClientFirstName, r.ClientLastName, 
    r.clientdob, r.Supervisorid, r.visitid, r.SuperName, r.SuperID, 
    r.colldate, r.colltime, r.OrderName, r.errorlogs, lv.date
```

Here is the output:

| Region_ID | messageid | DateReceived | DateModified | MessageStatus | clientid | ClientFirstName | ClientLastName | clientdob | Supervisorid | visitid | SuperName | SuperID | colldate | colltime | OrderName | errorlogs | last_visit_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 116113842 | 2022-06-09 13:07:52.000 | 2022-06-09 13:07:52.000 | 4 | 123456789 | Fake | Name | 1980-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 123 | 741852963 | Joe | J1234 | 2022-05-06 | 16:27:00 | fake_order | Supervisor Match not found | 2022-09-18 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 159753205 | 2022-03-12 04:07:55.000 | 2018-06-25 12:07:00.000 | 2 | 963741258 | Funny | Namely | 1999-02-03 00:00:00.000 | 98524 | 159654 | David | DL652 | 2018-01-24 | 09:03:00 | real_fake | Supervisor Match not found | 2022-05-11 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 951789369 | 2022-03-11 12:08:33.000 | 2022-03-11 12:08:33.000 | 2 | NULL | Who | Ami | 2000-08-11 00:00:00.000 | 789456 | 963123 | Shirley | S852 | 2017-05-14 | 09:30:00 | example_order | Client Match not found | NULL |
| 4 | 294615883 | 2017-09-06 16:20:00.000 | 2017-09-06 16:20:00.000 | 2 | NULL | Why | Tho | 1970-11-20 00:00:00.000 | 9631475 | 159654852 | Bob | B420 | 2022-09-22 | 10:25:31 | example_example | Client Match not found | NULL |
| 5 | 789963258 | 2022-07-11 15:22:40.000 | 2022-07-11 15:22:40.000 | 2 | NULL | Where | Aru | 1987-01-06 00:00:00.000 | 805690123 | 805460378 | Carlos | C999 | 2022-07-11 | 07:30:45 | order_order | Client Match not found | NULL |

Again, you will have to add back the `JOIN`s that I had to remove since the tables weren't included as well as some items in the `SELECT` list, the `WHERE` clause, and the 'GROUP BY` clause.